# How do I make Component rerender when props passed from parent and state changed?

Tags: reactjs, axios, react-props, react-state-management

I'm making a Todolist. The Submit component to handle input from user and make PUT request to the server to update the database. The Progress component shows the progress. When user submits, Submit will send props to Progress and Progress will call axios.get to get data and update the state. The props is passed successfully and the Progress state's variables do change but the component is not re-rendered.

submit.js

```
import Progress from './progress';

export default class Submit extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      updateProgress: 'No'
    }
  }

  handleSubmit = (e) => {
    // ...
    this.setState({updateProgress: 'Yes'}));
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
      <div style={{visibility: 'hidden'}}>
        <Progress update={this.state.updateProgress} />
      </div>

      // Form
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

progress.js

```
export default class Progress extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      tasksDone: 0
    };
  }  

  getData = () => {
    axios.get('/task')
    .then(res => {
      let resData = res.data[0];
      this.setState({tasksDone: resData.done});
    })
    .catch(err => console.log(err));
  }

  componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
    if (this.props.update != prevProps.update) {
      console.log('Props changed');
      this.getData();
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.getData();
  }

  render() {
    return (<div>You have done: {this.state.tasksDone}</div>)
  }
}
```

I know getData() won't be called again after the first submit because the props passed doesn't change but that's not the case because it doesn't work the first submit already.
When I use console.log(this.state.tasksDone) in componentDidUpdate() the tasksDone is updated but the div is not re-rendered, even I tried using forceUpdate() after calling getData().
I have read other questions and they said mutating state doesn't trigger re-render. Is my setState just mutating? I see changing state this way is very common. What am I missing?

Reproduce problem: https://codesandbox.io/s/determined-curie-ipr6v

Comment: Can you upload your code to https://codesandbox.io/?

Comment: You mean just the React or the Express and mongodb too?

Comment: You just only need to create Minimal, Reproducible Example on codesandbox 
https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Here, and I have put some console.log too: https://codesandbox.io/s/determined-curie-ipr6v

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem lies in your use for Progress.
The Progress you are updating is not the Progress that is shown on the display.

https://codesandbox.io/s/vigilant-ardinghelli-vd9nl
this is the working code you provided.

Comment: It seems working but what do you mean by "The Progress you are updating is not the Progress that is shown on the display"?

Comment: In your index.js, you declared a Progress to be displayed. Then again in your submit.js, you declared another Progress, but set it to hidden. The one you are updating is the hidden Progress inside submit.js.

Fix it by removing the Progress declared in index.js, and set visibility to true for the one in submit.js

Comment: @BrianeuqsarraT by importing Progress twice one at index and 1 at submit will create two instances of Progress component, It's like creating two objects from a single class. Then making changes to an object will not reflect on another object. Hence your changes in one instance is not reflecting in another.

Comment: Yea this makes sense, but in my source code, the purpose is to display the Submit form area (appears using Bootstrap Modal pop up) separated from the Progress area so I have to call <Progress /> inside  Submit to have a reference for passing props to, but I don't want it to appear right inside the form so I use style to hide it and import it inside App component to display it. Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: use some state management, such as react useContext, or redux. It will allow your to update components unrelated to each other.

Comment: OK, I have been hesitating to learn Redux but now I think it's time.